# How to install MapKit Plugin With Icenium?

Tags: cordova, plugins, telerik, mapkit, icenium

Today I tried adding the MapKit  plugin using "telerik Icenium" simply by downloading the plugin from github and moved the files under the plugin directory.

However when I tried to build it  I received "ERROR API_KEY variable".

I then tried to separate the plugin.xml to a specific platform "plugin.android.xml", then tried to build  the project and it went successfully. However when I tried the code below :

```
alert (typeof (window.mapKit || window.plugins.mapKit || window.MapKit);
```

I always get undefined. on both android and iOS

I have added the script tag as I usually do to all plugins, but nothing worked any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you install this plugin as a custom plugin with Telerik AppBuilder, you should be able to manage your API keys in the IDEs by clicking on the (highlighted) configure icon next to the plugin you added. See below as an example (this is in the plugin management section of your app's properties):

[image]

I'm guessing this is why you can't get the plugin to work. Also, you'll have to test on a physical device as custom plugins don't work in the simulator.

Comment: Yes am already aware of testing on device since the plugins are built on the cloud and packaged with the new binary file. Thanks for the answer i'll try this today